# Spring AOP Prototype-scoped Aspects are Firing out-of-order

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am using a set of Spring AOP Aspects (mostly from my library [here](https://github.com/kenwdelong/stability-utils)). I am finding that the ordering I specify for the aspects is no longer being respected (I am certain that, at some point in the past, say, 1 year ago on Boot 1.3.x, it was respected) when the scope of the aspect bean is "prototype".  If I remove the 'scope="prototype"' in XML, or the @Scope("prototype") in JavaConfig, the ordering is correct, but when the scope is prototype the ordering does not work - the aspects fire in apparently random order.  The aspects implement the Ordered interface.

Bean definitions follow the pattern (JavaConfig):

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public CircuitBreakerAspect circuitBreakerAspect()
{
    CircuitBreakerAspect aspect = new CircuitBreakerAspect();
    aspect.setGraphiteClient(graphiteClient);
    aspect.setOrder(100);
    return aspect;
}
```

I need the aspects to be prototype scope, because some of them (e.g., RetryInterceptor) are stateful (maintaining a count of failed operations, which is exported to JMX).  If I remove the prototype scope, the ordering works correctly but the same singleton aspect instance is used for all advised bean instances!

I am on Spring Boot 1.4.1 and Java 8.

How can I get prototype aspects to order correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Spring.  If I add the `@Order` annotation to the aspects, they order properly.  I've submitted a bug with Spring. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14959

Comment: Juergen notes this is on purpose; in Spring 5 they might be able to revisit.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the `prototype` scope is supported for aspects or more likely it does not make sense. Documentation at [11.2.6 Aspect instantiation models](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-instantiation-models) specifically mentions this:

> By default there will be a single instance of each aspect within the
>   application context.

To modify this behaviour, Spring AOP supports AspectJ `perthis` and `pertarget` instantiation models. Perhaps they will be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried both `perthis` and `pertarget` - didn't work.  First, you still need the `scope="prototype"` or the container won't start.  No biggie.  However, the "order" property is still not respected.  Grr, I've been using these aspects since 2007, never had this problem before...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it help me a lot!